# Easy string concatenation is giving an error "+@"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a url string by using the `request.env` values sent with every Rails request. Should be simple, but I'm getting a strange error.

The code:

```
 my_url = "https://" 
    + request.env['HTTP_HOST'] 
    + "something/"`
```

The error: `undefined method '+@' for "localhost:3000":String`

Any ideas what obvious thing I'm missing? Also tried using `request.env['HTTP_HOST'].to_s`, but that doesn't help.

Comment: By the way, it is kind of strange that you have to do this - you should be able to use Rails's built-in link generators. Why exactly are you creating a URL to your own server yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try embed the host in the string:

```
my_url = "https://#{request.env['HTTP_HOST']}something/"
```

Your code wraps the lines in bad places, instead, you can try:

```
my_url = "https://" + 
    request.env['HTTP_HOST'] +
    "something/"
```

The way you wrote it, they are 3 separate statements, and the code does this:

```
my_url = "https://" # set my_url to https://
+ request.env['HTTP_HOST'] # use + as an unary operator (kind of like -number), and throw away the result
+ "something/" # same thing
```

There is no unary + operator (taking a single argument) defined on strings.

Ruby interprets newlines as the end of each statement, except in cases where syntactically, the statement cannot end (eg. the last character is a + operator, or not all brackets are closed, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Guess you can't have strings being concatenated on multiple lines in a view. Put it all on one line and it fixes it.

Good:
`my_url = "https://" + request.env['HTTP_HOST'] + "something/"`

Bad:

```
my_url = "https://" 
  + request.env['HTTP_HOST'] 
  + "something/"
```